# How can update my theme and plugins without losing my changes?

Tags: wordpress, file, templates, plugins, updates

I am using wordpress! I have certain pluginsthat i use that I personally modified and made changes to.

I have even made edits to css files as well

I heard if you update the files , (when a update becomes available) the updates will overwrite the changes you have made

how can I avoid this?

**The  theme I am using is not a child theme i believe

Answer (score 0):

When updating WordPress, no theme or plugin files (except for the default WordPress themes maybe) will be overwritten.

When updating a plugin, plugin files will be overwritten indeed. A possible solution is – when that plugin is using hooks – to unhook and than re-hook them with your own copy of that function in the functions.php file of your theme. Furthermore, there is not much you can do.

With themes, it is best to create [child-themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).