# Wordpress PHP add code to plugin dissapears after updating

Tags: php, wordpress

How can we add code to a plugin so that it does not dissapear when updating the plugin? I cannot find any answer on the internet.

Comment: Fork the plugin.  Make your own.  Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002782/how-can-update-my-theme-and-plugins-without-losing-my-changes

Comment: Do you mean that I should use hooks? That a function automatically pastes the code into the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way.

Here some options:

- Create your own plugin;
- Don't update the original plugin (Not
  recommended);
- Try create your custom function on your child theme
  paste.

Comment: Does this mean I cannot use 3rd party plugins (with extra code) and update it without losing my changes?

Comment: @Jay yes, correct.

Comment: Ah okay, and what do you mean with the last option? I don't understand it that well

Comment: Oh btw, can I ask you to take a look at my other question maybe? It's about storing the WC API key safely.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ there are a lot of tutorials on internet about it.

Comment: I do already have a child theme. But what should I write in that custom function? I cannot recreate the plugin right?

Comment: Right, you cannot recreate the plugin in your child theme. In this case you have to fork the original plugin code and do your custom code and provide maintenance.